# How to Seed self referencing tree using Entity Framework Core 2.2

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

When I try to add migration there is the following exception:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Genre' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'SubGenres' set. To seed relationships, you need to add the related entity seed to 'Genre' and specify the foreign key values {'ParentId'}

How I can properly setup seed in `EntityFrameworkCore 2.2`

I have the next entity

```
public class Genre
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] [MaxLength(50)] public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GameGenre> GameGenre { get; set; } = new List<GameGenre>();
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre ParentGenre { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Genre> SubGenres { get; set; } = new List<Genre>();
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class OnlineGameContext : DbContext
{
    public OnlineGameContext(DbContextOptions<OnlineGameContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Genre>()
            .HasMany(u => u.SubGenres)
            .WithOne(p => p.ParentGenre)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentId);

       modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().HasData(DefaultGenresFactories.Action);
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
```

}

**Factories**

```
public static class DefaultGenresFactories
{
    public static Genre Action =>
        new Genre
        {
            Id = 5,
            Name = "Action",
            SubGenres = DefaultSubGenresFactories.Action
        };

}



public static class DefaultSubGenresFactories
 {
        public static ICollection<Genre> Action => new List<Genre>
        {
            new Genre
            {
                Id = 15,
                Name = "FPS",
                ParentId = 5
            },
            new Genre
            {
                Id = 16,
                Name = "TPS",
                ParentId = 5
            },
            new Genre
            {
                Id = 17,
                Name = "Misc",
                ParentId = 5
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message is telling you that you cannot use navigation properties when seeding with `HasData` method, but instead you could specify the relationships only via FK properties.

In other words, you can't use `SubGenres` and `ParentGenre` navigation properties for specifying the relations, they can be specified only via `ParentId` property.

So remove the

```
SubGenres = DefaultSubGenresFactories.Action
```

line, and either consolidate the `DefaultSubGenresFactories.Action` and `DefaultGenresFactories.Action` to a single list of `Genre` and use that list in `HasData` call, or if you want to keep the `DefaultGenresFactories` and `DefaultSubGenresFactories` classes separate as they are currently, simply call `HasData` for both (it's additive):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().HasData(DefaultGenresFactories.Action);
modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().HasData(DefaultSubGenresFactories.Action);
```

Comment: I have made changes which you recommended but I still have an issue ("**The seed entity for entity type 'Genre' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Id'.**" )
**Look screens:**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WW0mnFqk2iRzMCsggO9n2yiUfK1K-Yrv?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, I've tested it with the code from the question and it's working, so the original issue should be considered solved. What you are describing is a new issue and probably needs separate post. Anyway, may be in your real code you forget to provide `Id` for some `Genre` - for instance I don't see the `Adventure` definition in the screenshot. Note that you can't have entity `Id = 0` - it is considered "unassigned".

Comment: Adventure has Id = 6.
Look please repo https://github.com/valeraf23/OnlineGameStore/tree/SeedDataForContext

Comment: Ok, the new problem in the second `HasData` call - note that you are hitting `params object[]` overload and you are passing lists where EF Core expects objects. Either call `HasData` for each list, or concatenate them, e.g. `modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().HasData(DefaultSubGenresManager.Action(5).Concat(DefaultSubGenresManager.Races(4)).Concat(DefaultSubGenresManager.Strategy(1)));`